# Removing the text ellipsis / text overflow-wrap in HTML select element option text

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to disable text ellipsis ('...' at the end of text) / overflow-wrap  so as to be able to read the full text of the `option` element within the `select` element. At the moment the text is getting cut off even though there's plenty of white space left. The catch is that I have to do this using Greasemonkey (not written any code so far), just editing in browser console till I find the correct css option. Things I've tried so far:

1. changing an option/select width to "100%".
2. changing option/select line-height to "normal"
3. changing option/select padding to "0"
4. changing option/select font-size to something smaller.
5. setting option/select text-overflow to "clip"
6. setting option/select white-space to "normal"

   `var menu = document.querySelector('select');
   var option = document.querySelector('select option[value="neteng-deployment-agg-pod1-dub-primary"]');`

I'll also attach an image to help explain what I mean:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

My gut feeling that this is quite browser default specific, and that it would require browser-specific css hacks to change this, can you confirm if this is the same behaviour in all browsers on your machine?

edit: with knowledge that is same in all browsers:

there's a good chance replacing the default select element with some fancy jquery versions that replace select elements with mirror versions using normal html markup may solve it

https://sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins

Comment: tried this on firefox (52.x) and chrome (5x - 61.x)....same thing. It's not just my browser. This is an internal web application and its the same on all my colleague's machines / browsers too (I'm running windows 10, other's are running MAC OSX and Ubuntu).

Comment: in that case it may well be a decision that is being made ( similarly apparently in mac and windows) at an OS level,

I'd say there's a good chance replacing the default select element with some fancy jquery versions may solve it

https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but looks like IE problem.
First of all check the same page with Firefox and Google Chrome.

Comment: tried this on firefox (52.x) and chrome (5x - 61.x)....same thing. It's not just my browser. This is an internal web application and its the same on all my colleague's machines / browsers too (I'm running windows 10, other's are running MAC OSX and Ubuntu).